# IIS URL Rewrite 2 different URLs in one Rule using Conditions, is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have two different rewrite rules.

```
<rule name="Venue" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Venue/([_0-9a-z-(-)-,-]+)/([_0-9a-z-(-)-,-]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Main.asp?Type=Venue&amp;VenueID={R:1}&amp;VName={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
 </rule>
 <rule name="Venue" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Venue/([_0-9a-z-(-)-,-]+)/([_0-9a-z-(-)-,-]+)/([_0-9a-z-(-)-,-]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Main.asp?Type=Venue&amp;VenueID={R:1}&amp;VName={R:2}&amp;ConcertID={R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>
```

Is there a way to combine both rules into a single rule using `<conditions>`?
So when you go to either URL.

/Venue/37/The_Omni (You go to its page.)

/Venue/37/The_Omni/ConcertID/1 (You go to its page.)

(OR) Will I have to settle with two rules but with different names?

Answer (score 0):

Literally regular expression rules allow you to write,

```xml
<rule name="Venue" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Venue/([_0-9a-z-(-)-,-]+)/([_0-9a-z-(-)-,-]+)(?:/([_0-9a-z-(-)-,-]+))?" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Main.asp?Type=Venue&amp;VenueID={R:1}&amp;VName={R:2}{R:3:+&amp;ConcertID={R:3}}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

You might try and see if IIS URL Rewrite module supports such expressions.

Comment: I've been checking through pages of information but cannot find anything remotely close to what I am hoping for. It is not going to break me if it cannot be done. I was just wondering if it was possible. The site is already set up with both with their own names.

Comment: Have you tried the rules above? Does it work properly?